# Running Ansible Playbooks under uWSGI not working

Tags: python, uwsgi, ansible

I have Ansible Playbooks running from the command line just fine, since it seems Ansible uses the executing application (in this case Python) as the command to invoke Playbooks with.

Problem is when you try to run Ansible Playbooks under uWSGI, the command that attempts to run the Playbook uses /usr/bin/uwsgi.

Somehow Ansible is finding the command it is running under. Is there a way to change that?

UPDATE: I believe that the command to run is just sys.executable.  Is this overridable?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite understand the overall picture, but does it help if you're able to specify the interpreter per remote host using a "[behavioral-inventory-parameter](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters)":

> **ansible_python_interpreter** The target host python path. This is useful for systems with more than one Python or not located at
>   "/usr/bin/python" such as *BSD, or where /usr/bin/python is not a 2.X
>   series Python.  We do not use the "/usr/bin/env" mechanism as that
>   requires the remote user's path to be set right and also assumes the
>   "python" executable is named python, where the executable might be
>   named something like "python26".

e.g. this is how your inventory file would look like if you specify them at group level (you can also specify at host level of course, your choice):

```
# I think specifying ansible_ssh_host won't be needed, but if needed here is how it can be done.
# localhost ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python
[rhel5-boxes]
rhelhost1
# ...

# other groups...

[rhel5-boxes:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2.6

[rhel6-boxes]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python

[iron-boxes:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/ipython
```

Comment: Well that makes sense, but does this work for the localhost/127.0.0.1?  That seems to be hard-coded to sys.executable

Comment: Maybe this will work? [localhost]
127.0.0.1 ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: @LiteWait `[localhost]` would define a group not a host. I've added the line on how to do it for localhost. Still not quite clean on what the problem statement is so HTH. :-)